# Celery task will not execute in django

Tags: python, django, django-views, rabbitmq, celery

I am leraning Django using django 3 by example. I want to launch asynchronous task with celery. I set the settings but the task will not execute.
i'm using rabbit mq as broker and i'm using windows.
Here is my code:

celery.py

```
import os
from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'Onlineshop.settings')

app = Celery('Onlineshop')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

**init**.py

```
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

tasks.py

```
from celery import shared_task
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from .models import Order


@shared_task
def order_created(order_id):
    """Task to send an e-mail notification when order is successfully created."""
    order = Order.objects.get(id=order_id)
    subject = f'Order nr. {order.id}'
    message = f'Dear {order.first_name},\n\n' \
              f' You have successfully placed an order.' \
              f'Your order ID is {order.id}'

    mail_sent = send_mail(subject, message, 'admin@onlineshop.com', [order.email])
    return mail_sent
```

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import OrderItem
from .forms import OrderCreateForm
from cart.cart import Cart
from .tasks import order_created


# Create your views here.
@login_required
def order_create(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = request.user
        form = OrderCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            order = form.save(commit=False)
            order.user = user
            order.save()
            for item in cart:
                OrderItem.objects.create(order=order, product=item['product'], price=item['price'],
                                         quantity=item['quantity'])
            context = {
                'order': order,
            }
            # clear the cart
            cart.clear()
            # launch asynchronous task
            order_created.delay(order.id)
            return render(request, 'order/created.html', context)
    else:
        form = OrderCreateForm()
    context = {'cart': cart,
               'form': form,
               }
    return render(request, 'order/create.html', context)
```

Here is the problem in my view i called order_created function but the task will not execute and there in no email in my console.
my email settings are correct because other emails in my app works.
I use flower to monitor celery and in flower panel it shows that the tasks are executing but there is no email.
i would be happy if any body can help

Comment: Please share your backend email settings.

Comment: May I see some logs from celery as well as django and your settings.py to celery? You're 100% sure that this order_create function is executing?
P.S. Personally I am recommending redis in docker but i don't know how do run your rabbitmq.

Comment: @AbubakariUmarblacKrussainUma EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

Comment: @mka here is the logs :  [2021-12-18 17:08:44,616: INFO/MainProcess] celery@Matin ready.
[2021-12-18 17:08:44,616: INFO/MainProcess] Task orders.tasks.order_created[f0a95270-b690-4812-a2ad-569e7fb4fd83] received
[2021-12-18 17:08:44,616: INFO/MainProcess] Task orders.tasks.order_created[092f700d-d90d-4517-bd30-a6cba1bef509] received
[2021-12-18 17:08:44,616: INFO/MainProcess] Task orders.tasks.order_created[5863bbb4-516f-49b8-995b-68895560dedb] received

Comment: Do have celery run on a separate command prompt and your app on another ? because looking at your console log the task was successful and you should get  message in  the console  where app is being run.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Okay by running the command Rabbitmq-server restart and also to get celery to connect to the server by running the command Celery -A app_name worker --loglevel=info. Try this task scheduler

```
@shared_task
def order_created(order_id):
    """ Task to send an e-mail notification when an order is successfully created"""
    order = Order.objects.get(id=order_id)
    subject = 'Order nr. {}'.format(order.id)
    message = 'Dear {},\n\nYou have sucsessfully placed an order. Your order id is {}'\
                  .format(order.first_name,order.id)
    
    mail_sent = send_mail(subject,
                           message,
                           'admin@onlineshop.com',
                            [order.email])
    
    return mail_sent
```

Comment: i tried this but it does not work

Comment: Okay try  removing the WAL file the service started. Locate the WAL in /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia with find /var/lib/rabbitmq/ -name "*.wal" and remove it. Restart the service afterwards. make sure you run celery in a separate  command prompt and your app in a different one as well.

Comment: i'm using windows i don't have this directories

Comment: C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ\db\rabbit@computername-mnesia\quorum\rabbit@computername

Comment: i have deleted the file and run it again but still there is no email log but the task is executed in celery logs : [2021-12-19 11:56:32,864: INFO/MainProcess] Events of group {task} enabled by remote.
[2021-12-19 11:56:51,707: INFO/MainProcess] Task orders.tasks.order_created[f18bfe64-28b8-4bc1-9d2e-968304832fd1] received
@AbubakariUmarblacKrussainUma